# Access a JSON value while iterating over array in HandleBar jsp

Tags: jsp, handlebars.js, aem

I have a json with the below values(Sample).

```
[  
   {  
      "sectionTitle":"LATEST NEWS",
      "language":"ENGLISH",
      "sectionLink":"/content/ml/sample.html",
      "newTab":"",
      "ViewType":"slrr",
      "bgColor":"red",
      "fontColor":"white",
      "logo":"",
      "articleNewTab":"true",
      "Results":[ 
        {  "title":"sample title",
          "description":"sample desc"},
        {
         "title":"sample title1",
          "description":"sample desc1"}
    ],
      "morelinkJson":{  
         "moreLink":"/content/mm/ml/news/just-in.html",
         "moreLinkNewTab":false
      }
   }
]
```

Here i have displaying the "Results" by iterating using

```
{{#each this.0.Results}}
```

Inside this loop i want to access the values- sectionTitle, language ...etc.
But I cant.
I am using handlebar jsp here.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them using `{{@root.0.someThing}}` pattern.

```
{{#each this.0.Results}}
      <div class="entry">
        <h1>{{title}}{{@root.0.sectionTitle}}</h1> 
        <div class="body">
          {{@root.0.language}}
          {{description}}
        </div>
      </div>
{{/each}}
```

**See at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHwhcq?p=preview)**